# mysql phpmyadmin update query based on another column in multiple rows based on value in each row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin:

Mysql table A has two columns A_id int, A_name varchar and

table B has three columns B_id int, B_name varchar, A_name varchar.

Now I require to change table B as B_id int, B_name varchar, A_id int where A_id is based on A_name inserted before in table B.

I have thousands of rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
  [table1_name] AS t1 
  INNER JOIN [table2_name] AS t2 ON t1.column1_name] = t2.[column1_name] 
SET 
  t1.[column2_name] = t2.column2_name];
```